# Receiving and sending notifications from database

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm not much familiar with Task Api programming in C#. Can anyone review my following code?

The following is a `ElapsedEventHandler` of a `System.Timers.Timer`. In this event, I'm getting pending notifications from database and sending them. After I send the notification, I update that notification in database by setting `HasSent = true`. We require our notifications to be sent as soon as possible. This is the reason, I'm updating `HAsSent` in a separate thread by using Task Api. I would like to know if this is a bad practise? Should I use this? If not then why?

```
protected void ProcessNotifications(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    UtilityMethods.StopTimer(_notificationTimer);

    try
    {
        var notificationService = new NotificationService();
        var pendingNotifications = notificationService.GetPendingNotifications();

        if (pendingNotifications.Count > 0 && LoadConfigurations())
        {
            foreach (var notification in pendingNotifications)
            {
                try
                {
                    var notificationType = (NotificationType)notification.NotificationTypeId;

                    notification.NotificationTemplate = new NotificationTemplateService().GetById(notification.NotificationTemplateId);
                    notification.NotificationAttachments = notificationType == NotificationType.Email ?
                        new NotificationAttachmentService().GetByNotificationId(notification.NotificationId) : null;

                    using (var sender = NotificationSenderFactory.Create(notificationType))
                    {
                        if (sender.Send(notification))
                        {
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                notificationService.MarkNotificationsAsSent(notification.NotificationId);// A database Hit
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    AppLogger.LogException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogger.LogException(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        UtilityMethods.StartTimer(_notificationTimer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use this?

**NO**

> If not then why?

Reference [TaskFactory.StartNew Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> ### [Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the [`Task.Run`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2) method is the recommended way to launch a compute-bound task. Use the [`StartNew`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2) method only when you require fine-grained control for a long-running, compute-bound task. **.......**

Which would end up as

```
//...omitted for brevity

Task.Run(() => {
    notificationService.MarkNotificationsAsSent(notification.NotificationId);// A database Hit
});

//...omitted for brevity
```

Comment: Is it good to run a task in loop? Or I should hit the database without task? Would it really a good way to achieve performance or it can degrade performance?